# Why does HashSet say it does not contain this Object?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I am trying to print "Contains", however, the HashSet is not detecting the Integer[] value.  Does it have to do with it being Passed By Reference?  How can I overcome this if I do not want to pass the actual Integer[] object into the method's arguments?

```
import java.util.*;

public class passByReference2{
    public static void method(HashSet<Integer[]> visited){
        Integer[] n = {1, 2};
        if (visited.contains(n)){
            System.out.println("Contains");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        HashSet<Integer[]> visited = new HashSet<Integer[]>();
        Integer[]v = {1, 2};
        visited.add(v);
        method(visited);
    }


}
```

Comment: *Nothing* in Java is passed by reference. It is pass-by-value only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because arrays don't implement `hashCode` in a way which compares elements - in fact, arrays don't override `hashCode` (or `equals`) at all, so the implementation from `Object` is used.

The `hashCode` and `equals` for an array are purely based on identity.

---

If you want to "overcome" it, use a type which calculates `hashCode` and `equals` based upon element values, e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: They don't implement `equals`, either, so they inherit the default implementation that uses `==`.

Comment: @user2357112 true, updated.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the default `hashCode` implementation is to use the address of the object.

> This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

[hashCode() javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())